# rendering forms and widget in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am developing a website and I would like to personalized how the forms are rendered.

My purpose is for each field I should achieve this structure

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for=":id">:LABEL</label>
   <input type=":type" class="form-control" id=":id" />
</div>
```

In case of checkbox, the input must to appear first and without class atribute

Answer (score 0):

The options for doing this are listed in [Symfony Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig) documentation.

In your form theme Twig file (normally `app/Resources/views/form.html.twig`) you should add something like this:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }} {# Can remove this unless you want inline errors #}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim}) %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've achieved something writing on base.html.twig 
but I don't like this solution. I prefer to have it in a separate file.

Comment: Did you add the form.html.twig to your Twig config, to make it global?  For what you are doing I don't think using the form file itself as the theme file makes sense. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig

Answer (score 0):

The Ryan answer has needed to add one more line like this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }} {# Can remove this unless you want inline errors #}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim}) %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

as per symfony2 documentation [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)  the current template in which u want to make change , u will have to write the line

> {% form_theme form _self %}

in the starting of any block overriding ..

Comment: the field should be `app/Resources/views/form.html.twig`. I have it on that file but doesn't work. However `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` works perfectly